# Python3 script runs fine from shell but triggers UnicodeEncodeError within PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x, character-encoding

Consider the following script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print("<h1>é</h1>")
```

I am trying to run it from PHP :

```
<?php
    system("/usr/bin/python3 /my/script.py");
?>
```

It works fine from shell, but crashes through PHP :

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

And if I add `.encode('utf-8')` PHP prints the byte encoded string :

> b'\xc3\xa9'

How can I fix it ?  Adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the python script or prefixing the string with `u` didn't help, and I thought utf-8 was supposed to be the default for python3 anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is to set `PYTHONIOENCODING` explicitely :

```
<?php
    system("PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 /usr/bin/python3 /my/script.py");
?>
```

[[Credits.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41223807/812102)]